# how to find out broadcast receiver is called?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use usb serial port but all example I've seen use broadcast receiver. in their code they give a pending intent to UsbSeialManager.requestPermission(pi). now i want to know if there is a way to see if onReceive() is called or not. and to wait for it.
I need a method that return correct usb(onReceive() is called)
P.S. I'm making a class for each connected usb.

Answer (score 0):

Within the help of `Log.d("key","value");` you can print the log to identify that `onReceive()` is called or not